Issue with url rewriting in ASP.NET MVC using C#
I am working on an ASP.NET MVC app with C#, and I'm trying to do URL rewriting in the route config file. I want to change the URL for the view page. StoryIS parameter is passed. The URl that is working before is
Admin/Story/ViewDescription?storyId=1 

and I want to change it to View/(StoryID). Can you please guide me? If anything else is required kindly comment.
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "ViewDescription",
              url: "View/{StoryID}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Story", action = "ViewDescription", StoryID = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );

This is the controller I am using for the view.
public ActionResult ViewDescription(int StoryID)
{
        if (StoryID <= 0)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid Story ID");
        }

        List<AddStoryDTO> titleWithDescriptions = bll.Viewdescription(StoryID);
        List<ReviewDTO> reviews = bll.GetReviews(StoryID);

        if (titleWithDescriptions != null && titleWithDescriptions.Count > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Reviews = reviews; 
            return View(titleWithDescriptions);
        }
        else
        {
            return HttpNotFound("No descriptions found for the provided Story ID.");
        }
}


Have you tried change name to "default"?

@Borntocode The default is already written in the route config file.  routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
like this

What exactly is the problem because your routes.MapRoute code works fine.

@vdwwd I know the routes.MapRoute code is fine, that is the problem because I am not getting the required URL, The URL I am getting is not working, the old URL Admin/Story/ViewDescription?storyId=1 is working but I want view/storyID. Is anything else required, I will provide that

Like i said it works fine. Added your route. Then added ViewDescription ActionResult to a controller Story and it worked perfectly.

@vdwwd That's what I am saying, it is correct but I am not getting my required URL.
